# An option for flagging comments in mobile view

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, mobile-web

There is an option for flagging comments in the desktop version, whereby comments can be flagged as rude or abusive. This option is not valid in mobile view, only voting on comments is available.

So, the option to flag comments should be added to the mobile view as fast as possible.

Comment: I just switch to full site view or the app. Both support flagging comments.

Comment: OK. I'll take the app.